# Tomcat6 - 2 wars, 2 hosts

Tags: configuration, tomcat6, war

I have 2 war files app1.war and app2.war.
I have 2 hostnames domain1.com and domain2.com.

I have one desk top running ubuntu and tomcat6.

I would like to know how to configure tomcat to serve app1 for domain1.com and app2 for domain2.com.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need apache-httpd in front of your tomcat, then you need to configure the rewrite module.

Comment: An example would have been great